# Custom metrics not found in prometheus when setting up a simple python app with prometheus + kubernetes + minikube + docker

Tags: python, docker, kubernetes, prometheus, minikube

I'm currently learning the prometheus + docker + kubernetes stack and use minikube for kubernetes simulation (instead of the cloud). In my setup, I create a simple flask app which should log metrics to prometheus. The setup is as follows:

**app.py**

```
from flask import Flask, request
from prometheus_client import Counter, start_http_server

app = Flask(__name__)

# Prometheus metrics
REQUEST_COUNTER = Counter('http_requests_total', 'Total HTTP Requests', ['method', 'endpoint'])

@app.route('/log', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def log_request():
    REQUEST_COUNTER.labels(method=request.method, endpoint='/log').inc()
    return "Request logged"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Start Prometheus metrics server on port 8001
    start_http_server(8001)
    # Run the Flask app
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8000, debug=False)
```

**Dockerfile**

```
# Use an official Python runtime as a parent image
FROM python:3.9-slim

# Set the working directory in the container
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# Copy the current directory contents into the container
COPY . .

# Install Flask and Prometheus client
RUN pip install flask prometheus_client

# Make port 8000 available to the world outside this container
EXPOSE 8000
EXPOSE 8001

# Run app.py when the container launches
CMD ["python", "./app.py"]
```

**deployment.yaml**

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: flask-app
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: flask-app
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: flask-app
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: flask-app
        image: my-flask-app:latest
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8000
        - containerPort: 8001
```

**service.yaml**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: flask-app-service
  labels:
    app: flask-app
spec:
  selector:
    app: flask-app
  ports:
  - name: http  # Name for the first port
    protocol: TCP
    port: 8000
    targetPort: 8000
  - name: metrics  # Name for the second port
    protocol: TCP
    port: 8001
    targetPort: 8001
```

**servicemonitor.yaml**

```
apiVersion: monitoring.coreos.com/v1
kind: ServiceMonitor
metadata:
  name: flask-app-monitor
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: flask-app
  endpoints:
  - port: "8001"
```

I installed prometheus in the minikube environment using helm with `helm upgrade --install prometheus prometheus-community/kube-prometheus-stack`. Further, I ran the following commands to start the pod and do port forwarding:

```
kubectl apply -f deployment.yaml
kubectl apply -f service.yaml
kubectl apply -f servicemonitor.yaml
kubectl port-forward svc/prometheus-kube-prometheus-prometheus 9090:9090 --namespace default
kubectl port-forward svc/flask-app-service 8001:8001
kubectl port-forward svc/flask-app-service 8000:8000
```

All the pods seem to be running correctly, and I can go to localhost:8001, which shows me all metrics. However, when going to the prometheus UI at localhost:9090, it does not seem to find the flask-app and its metrics. Do you know what is going wrong and why the Prometheus UI does not show any metrics from my flask app (and thus does not allows me to do any queries for this custom metric)?